# Ionic - age number spinner component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mobile, ionic-framework, spinner

Working on a hybrid mobile app, and encountered this problem.

I'm currently adding new items to my left side menu, and one of the new component is age number (min:18 , max:65) spinner. Search through the web and Ionic docs, but didn't find any components similar to it.

[Age number spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hr6PP.png)

For now I only have labels as number input fields, only as a placeholder.

```
<div class="match-age">
        <label class="item item-input min-age">
          <input type="number" min="18" max="65">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input max-age">
          <input type="number" min="18" max="65">
        </label>
      </div>
```

And it looks like this: [Current design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1U7H9.png)

My template for this submenu looks like this:

```
<ion-list ng-if="(menuMatch && !menuMain)" class="slide-right-left">
      <div class="item item-divider main-menu-divider">
        {{ "distance" | translate }}
      </div>
      <div class="item range">
        <input type="range" name="distance" min="0" max="200" value="{{rangeValue}}" ng-model="rangeValue"
               step="10">
        {{ rangeValue }}
      </div>
      <div class="item item-divider main-menu-divider">
        {{ "age" | translate }}
      </div>
      <div class="match-age">
        <label class="item item-input min-age">
          <input type="number" min="18" max="65">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input max-age">
          <input type="number" min="18" max="65">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-divider main-menu-divider">
        {{ "match_with" | translate }}
      </div>
      <div class="match-options">
        <ion-radio class="man-option" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'men'">Men</ion-radio>
        <ion-radio class="woman-option" ng-model="choice" ng-value="'women'">Women</ion-radio>
      </div>

      <div href="" ng-click="saveMatchOptions()">
        <button class="button save-options">
          {{ "save_options_btn" | translate }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
```

If there is not something similar to that in the framework, I could try to make custom html component and add some functionality with Javascript, and styles it with CSS, in order to create something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the question here is, but as I didn't find a component achieving the production level I was aiming for (nor in the UX or customisation aspect)  I've created a new directive currently used in our live mobile app. The number picker / spinner is implemented as an attribute directive, so stick to any DOM element, or your existing input fields (just remember to set their css to read only) and voila, solve a bunch of headaches (input verifications, user churn, etc.)
The directive acts as you'd expect it, with drag capability as in native devices, with a slick look, highly customizable and plenty additional functionality.
Check it out!
http://market.ionicframework.com/plugins/ion-number-picker (LINK UPDATE THANKS TO @strttn)

Comment: Updated link to referenced plugin: https://market.ionicframework.com/plugins/ion-number-picker